# Tcl on osx: Open pipe for reading: No `readable` event generated on EOF

Tags: macos, tcl, event-driven

I'll try to be specific. This is OSX-Yosemite, Tcl 8.5.9. I'm doing something like that:

```
            set fd [open "|$external"]

            fconfigure $fd -blocking 0 -buffering line
            fileevent $fd readable "set $tracername $fd"
```

This `tracername` holds the name of a global variable (with ::namespace-based name), which is next used here:

```
    # Ok, now clear the variable
    set $tracername ""

    # If vwait causes error, it may happen that the process
    # has finished before it could be added to the event list
    # (just the script had no opportunity to see it). If this
    # happens, just go on, and in the next roll you'll find it out anyway.
    $mkv::debug "--- Waiting for an event from any of fileevent-registered processes ($tracername)..."
    catch {vwait $tracername}

    $mkv::debug "--- UNBLOCKED BY: $tracername=[set $tracername]"
```

This works perfectly on Linux and Cygwin. On Mac it stalls on `vwait` (to the best of my knowledge).

This `catch` is here added just for a case when all "files" from the fileevent have been closed - according to the documentation, doing `vwait` when no events were scheduled results in exception of type error (to prevent waiting forever). However I doubt this is the case here because the command started is a C++ compiler command call that takes at least more than half a second to run.

The program is a Tcl version of `make` tool and this code is a part of parallel build support. This happens when I run without parallel support. If I run at least 2 process simultaneously, everything works fine.

What I observe when debugging is that the child process spawned by `open |$external` stops printing anything on the output, so looxlike it has finished. But normally I have a `readable` event generated, which gives me opportunity to check if `[eof $fd]` and close it.

Comment: Any chance of trying with a later version of Tcl, or are you committed to using the system version?

Comment: Theoretically I could install a newer version from brew, but I thought this version should be good enough. Interesting: no problems on trial app doing the same.

There's a simple method if you want to help me. This project is available here: http://gitlab.com/silvercat/silvercat - go to `examples/tclmake` and issue `../../bin/make.tcl`  - when I test it on this Mac, it hangs on `vwait` (even with -j 2!). On Linux everything is fine.

I know how stupid it is to ask to debug my code, but OTOH this may happen to be an interesting testcase for Tcl on Mac.